# Gradle Sync failed | Failed to resolve : com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.0

Tags: android

I have discovered that in order to used the Google Places API, I need to add this to my build.gradle(app) file

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.0
```

When I click **sync**, I get this error:

> > Gradle Sync failed | Failed to resolve : com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.0

Please what do I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue more than likely is that you need to add google maven repo in your root `build.gradle`.  The other thing to be aware of is that from v11.2.0 onwards you need to set `compileSdkVersion` to at least v26 (and also use v26 or later of support libraries).

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad! Thought I added that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [Google Maven repository](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven) to your root Gradle file. Adjust the root script's `allprojects` block to add the Google repo:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```